# Why downloads on site A are fast, but downloads from site B are slow, only on my network

Tags: internet, routing, internet-speed

So, I have WiFi set up. Site A downloads really fast, but site B downloads really slow. Site B is slow only on my WiFi. If I switch to mobile data, its a blazing fast download. Why?

Could it be because my ISP has bad routing across the internet, and my mobile data ISP has better routing?

Answer (score 1):

One reason this could occur is if Site B has a peering arrangement with your mobile provider. If so, once your packets reach your mobile network they can go straight to Site B, while packets might have to go over some slow route to reach.